# How to have Delete Cascade on both column that refer the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, cascading-deletes

I have a tables of Items:

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | GrandParent |
| 2 | Parent1 |
| 3 | Parent2 |
| 4 | Child1 |

and a table of ItemRelations:

| ParentItemId | ChildItemId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |

I am trying to have a foreign key with a delete cascade on both ParentItemId and ChildItemId to the itemTable,
When i delete GrandParent, i want to keep the relation between Parent1 and Child1
but SQL is not letting me :

> '- Unable to create relationship 'FK_BlockRelations_Child'.
> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_BlockRelations_Child' on table
> 'BlockRelations' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify
> ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN
> KEY constraints. Could not create constraint or index. See previous
> errors.'

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Comment: Are you trying to point both parentItemId and childItemId to ID column in parent table. Do you have any other table with name BlockRelations which you did not post here. Issue seems to be with that table

Answer (score 0):

The concept of parent/grandparent seems unnecessary because if you have a recursive thing going on and at any point, an item can be a child, grand parent or parent.

In any case, you are trying to give conflicting instructions to the database:

On one hand you are saying that "I am trying to have a foreign key with a delete cascade on both ParentItemId and ChildItemId to the itemTable"
and then in the next sentence "When i delete GrandParent, i want to keep the relation between Parent1 and Child1 but SQL is not letting me"

When you decide to create a cascade delete, it means you are doing 2 things:

1. Enforcing foreign key constraints - zero tolerance for orphans
2. Based on those foreign key constraints, you are enforcing an action of deleting everything in Item Relations linked to Items when an item is deleted

Once you enforce (1) then you will not be allowed to add an item into the Item Relations without it first existing in items.

If you then do a cascade delete action based on enforcing #1, then you need to choose which field you use it on. Can't be both unless both are each linked to different tables or one is made to cascade and the other has a no action.

If on the other hand you want to delete grandparent and leave items in Item Relations, what you are saying is that you don't want #1 anymore - no foreign constraint enforcement and a tolerance for orphans.

Once you decide which you want, the right approach should be clear.

You may need to completely abandon foreign key constraint enforcement and consider insert and delete triggers if your delete cascades and foreign key enforcements are conditional and based on the values of the parent.

Comment: Say i want to delete Parent1. The end result wanted is to delete all itemRelations where parent1 is either the parent or the child.

i would have to do 1 delete cascade on ParentItemId and a delete trigger for when it is the child?

Comment: Ideally what you want is a self-referencing foreign key on ItemRelations that cascade deletes on itself when it is triggered by a cascade delete or a delete trigger from items but the DBMS will not allow it so what you actually need is a delete trigger on the ItemRelations and then when detected, use a recursive CTE to find all the related ids  and delete them all.